# Find common dictionary values in list of dictionary - python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a single list of dictionaries as such:

```
[{'Y': 80, 'X': 70, 'C': 0, 'L': 'B'}, {'Y': 81, 'X': 71, 'C': 1, 'L': 'C'}, {'Y': 82, 'X': 72, 'C': 2, 'L': 'D'}, {'Y': 82, 'X': 72, 'C': 3, 'L': 'E'}, {'Y': 83, 'X': 73, 'C': 4, 'L': 'F'}]
```

broken down so easier to read

```
{'Y': 80, 'X': 70, 'C': 0, 'L': 'B'}

{'Y': 81, 'X': 71, 'C': 1, 'L': 'C'}

{'Y': 82, 'X': 72, 'C': 2, 'L': 'D'}

{'Y': 82, 'X': 72, 'C': 3, 'L': 'E'}

{'Y': 83, 'X': 73, 'C': 4, 'L': 'F'}
```

and I want to find the two dictionaries where 'Y' and 'X' are the same. Then delete one of the two dictionary and update the resulting 'C'

```
{'Y': 80, 'X': 70, 'C': 0, 'L': 'B'}

{'Y': 81, 'X': 71, 'C': 1, 'L': 'C'}

{'Y': 82, 'X': 72, 'C': 2, 'L': 'D'}

{'Y': 83, 'X': 73, 'C': 3, 'L': 'F'}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, does it matter which of the two dictionaries with the same values of `'Y'` and `'X'` is deleted? It would be more convenient to keep the last and delete the others, unlike your example. Also, in your example, the final dictionary in your input list has the value `4` for the key `'C'` but the result has the value `3`.

Comment: No it does not matter which dictionary is deleted. The goal is to have unique 'Y' and 'X'. C represents a counter, so want to update that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
d = [
{'Y': 80, 'X': 70, 'C': 0, 'L': 'B'},
{'Y': 81, 'X': 71, 'C': 1, 'L': 'C'},
{'Y': 82, 'X': 72, 'C': 2, 'L': 'D'},
{'Y': 82, 'X': 72, 'C': 3, 'L': 'E'},
{'Y': 83, 'X': 73, 'C': 4, 'L': 'F'}
]



Xs = [] 
Ys = []
c = 0
out = []

for i in range(len(d)):
  obj = dict(d[i]) # Copy the dict at index i
  if (obj["X"], obj["Y"]) in XYs:
    XYs.append((obj["X"], obj["Y"]))
  else:
    obj["C"] = c
    c = c + 1
    out.append(obj)
    XYs.append((obj["X"], obj["Y"]))
```

Edit: improved it by storing unique tuples